# From Date & To Date Validation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to validate for From Date & To Date ie., From Date should not be greater than To Date but it can be same & Dates are in the format '03-MAR-2012'...please help me.you can change date format as you like if it necessary.but it should not affact my actual date value..

Comment: -1 for using "u" instead of "you"

Comment: How is the user entering these dates?

Comment: i used jquery calender..user can select date from that calender..

Answer (score -1):

first compare year if it is ok then compare month then day use nested if conditions

Comment: but month is not integers...examples 03-JAN-2012,03-MAY-2012,03-DEC-2012 etc..using nested if we can validate only date and year..not month..

Comment: use "select" for month show name and give number as value like 1 2 3 ... and u get number there

Comment: <select><option value='1'>Jan</option><option value='2'>Feb</option></select>

Comment: oh god..that date is an input from user..i just need a code to validate dates in that format..please dont think about user input..

Comment: i have a text filed..user can not type anything on it..instead i called a jquery function which will display a calender near to that text filed..user can choose a date by clicking on the calender..